# android:scrollHorizontally not working on Samsung Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface, marquee

In my music player application, I have got a TextView with Artist, Title and so on, which is scrolling horizontally in the View. (Like the old html marquee tag). It works on Android 2.3.4 on Xperia Arc but doesn't work on Samsung Galaxy Nexus (The Text is just displayed and not scrolling). The TextView is defined like this. In the code it is just set with the matching Songtext.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songArtist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFA" /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way - adding:

```
        android:singleLine="true"
```

does the trick...